# How to store uploaded files in a directory of the main domain from a subdomain upload form

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, webserver

please how can store uploaded file in my main domain directory should it be like this:

```
move_uploaded_file(https://example.com/uploads)
```

Comment: How are your web server folders structured? Typically you will find something like `/var/www/html` and `/var/www/subdomain/` for Linux Apache.

Comment: some like public_html/ for main domain and subdomain.example.com/ for subdomain....the subdomain folders are not in public_html

Comment: Do these files already exist in the subdomain or are you uploading the files through a form?

Comment: am uploading tru forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to start here with handling uploaded files:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

The first example is almost exactly what you want:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
        $name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

You will need to make two edits. The `$uploads_dir` will need to have a relative path to where the files are uploaded. Let's say your form is in the root of your subdomain in `subdomain.example.com/` and you want to move them to `public_html/uploads`. Your new `$uploads_dir` should look like the following:

```
$uploads_dir = __DIR__ . '/../public_html/uploads';
```

`__DIR__` will give you the current director your php file is running in. This allows you to create a relative path to other directories.

The second edit is to update the `$_FILES` array to loop through the proper structure of what you are uploading. It might not be pictures as in the example.

Comment: It would be a good idea to define the path to upload somewhere in your application. That can be in the database stored with each file details, or it can be in the application config. Either works.

Comment: please the home directory is /home/user and in this directory we have public_html and also subdomain. so the subdomain absolute directory is home/user/subdomain. while main domain directory is home/user/public_html ...and the form is located home/user/subdomain/form.php

Answer (score 0):

This would be a quick and dirty way to do it( assuming you're in the root directory of your subdomain and your main domain is its own folder( if your main directory does not have its own folder remove the 2nd chdir)

Im assuming youre uploading an image. if not make the changes as necessary

```
chdir(dirname("../"));// this takes you up one level
chdir("main_directory");// use this only if main directory is inside a folder

 $filepath = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
                    mkdir($filepath, 0755);// this is only to create a new images folder if it doesnt exist
                }
                chdir($filepath);
                $filename = 'file_name_you_want';
                $info = pathinfo($_FILES['img']['name']);
                $ext = $info['extension'];
                $newname = $filename . "." . $ext;
                $types = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png');
                if (in_array($_FILES['img']['type'], $types)) {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $newname)) {
                        $img_path = 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newname;

                    } else {
                         // do what needs to be done
                    }
```

If youre using php 7 you might want to take a look at string

```
 dirname ( string $path [, int $levels = 1 ] );// the 2nd param would be how many levels up you want to go and $path can be your current directory using __DIR__
```

Comment: can't i not do something like this : ./public_html/uploads